# How to get product related information from customer when he add a product to cart?

Tags: magento

i want to attach a form to a product and when customer want to add that product to cart he should fill in the info in this form 1st.

And that information must be attached with the purchased details.

**for example**

i want to get size information (like length, neck, waiste, sleaves, chest etc) from the customer when he wishes to purchase a product. and then this information must be sent with the  purchased details (or may be in email etc)

How to approach towards this solution.

**Right now i am using custom options for it. but this is not a good solution cuz i believe there must be better approach than that**

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom form module, there are free form extension in magento connect.

And then add the form into the view.phtml, add your script to enable the "add-cart" button only after submitted the form.

Is this the flow you expected?